# Does there exist a linear transformation in the space of all polynomials of degree at most 2 such that:

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

- $T(1+x) = x^2$
- $T(1 + x^2) = 1 - x + x^2$
- $T(x^2 + x) = 1 + 3x^2$

I began by attempting to find the inverse of the following matrix with column vectors corresponding to the coefficients of the untransformed vectors. However, the matrix is singular. Does this mean that there is no such linear transformation?
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}

Comment: By using linearity of T and adding and subtracting these appropriately, you can probably find what T does to the basis elements... Also, just because a matrix is singular does not prohibit the existence of such a transform - it just means that the thing is not an isomorphism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any linear map is determined by its values in a basis. Since $\{1+x,1+x^2,x^2+x\}$ is a basis for $P_2(\Bbb R)$, one writes a polynomial of degree two as a combination $$p(x) = A(1+x) + B(1+x^2) + C(x+x^2)$$where the coefficients $A,B$ and $C$ are functions of the coefficients of $p(x)$. Then we'll have, by the linearity imposed, that: $$\begin{align}T(p(x)) &= AT(1+x)+BT(1+x^2)+CT(x+x^2)\\ &=A+C - Bx + (A+B+3C)x^2\end{align}.$$

Comment: Thank you. The problem then asks me to find the matrix that completes the linear transformation. This would simply be the inverse of the isomorphism of that last equation? I hope I'm using the right vocab here, I apologize if I sound silly because I haven't done enough with linear transformations yet.

Comment: To find the explicit expression for $T$, you need to carry out the boring computations of $A$, $B$ and $C$ there. Then you can represent $T$ by a matrix, using some basis of your choice. For example, if you check that ${\cal C}=\{ x^2,1-x-x^2,1+3x^2 \}$ is a basis for $P_2(\Bbb R)$, and if ${\cal B}$ is the basis we had from the start, then $[T]^{\cal B}_{\cal C}$ will be the identity.